# C# ListView: how to concatenate properly

Tags: c#, listview

I have the following code:

```
CSA.Subitems.add(read["firstname"+#middlename"+" lastname"].tostring());
```

I need to concatenate *firstname*, *middlename* and *lastname* to a single string to be displayed in a single cell on `ListView`. Since in the database, the three entries can be different or not together.

But, I am getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` error. Any clues?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: It would be easier to combine them while you were selecting the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  string[] saLvwItem = new string[3];


  saLvwItem[0] = read["firstname"].ToString();
  saLvwItem[1] = read["middlename"].ToString();
  saLvwItem[2] = read["lastname"].ToString();

  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(saLvwItem[0]+" "+saLvwItem[1]+" "+saLvwItem[2]);

  CSA.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here in this link, You can see the String.Concat method in C#.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2